# Максимальное количество получателей в электронном сообщении Gmail. (Cc, Bcc, To, Reply-To)

Tags: email, gmail

Я нашел информацию(в самом электронном сервисе Gmail), что поля cc, bcc и to могут содержать максимум 100 ресипиентов, так ли это? Про Reply-To не нашел, подскажите, пожалуйста, возможно плохо ищу(скорее всего). Информация необходима, так-как посредствам ORM фреймворка хочу ограничить филд, в соответствии с ограничениями самого сервиса Gmail.

Comment: По крайней мере в [RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5322) никаких ограничений на размер списков адресов нет. google протухает?

Comment: я не знаю, что протухает, а что нет. 
Вот: https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852/gmail-sending-limits-in-google-workspace?hl=en#limits

Comment: По вашей ссылке (гугл сам признается ...) cc, bcc (это в хедерах письма, в том тексте что передается после DATA в esmtp протоколе) максимум 2000 (из них внешних (адреса не @gmail.com) максимум 500), а в самом потоке протокола можно передавать не более 100 RCPT TO. Ну, вот такую почтовую систему им удалось сваять -)